# MySQL Multiple Group-By Count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I'm trying to count some results from a query. I've been through the various examples on here but none of them are *adaptable* enough to do what I'm trying to do.

If someone could take a look, point out where I'm going wrong, and kindly put me out of my misery, that would be wonderful. Thank-you.

**Four Tables: Areas, Departments, Systems and Checks**

*Each Area has many Departments. Each Department has many Systems; and each System has many Checks. I'm trying to find out how many **different** Systems (by System_ID) have been checked in the previous week.*

**Current Query**

```
Select
a.Area_Name,
d.Department_Name,
s.System_ID,
s.System_Name,
c.Check_Date

from departments d

left join areas a
on a.Area_ID = d.Department_Area

left join systems s
on s.System_Department = d.Department_ID

left join checks c
on c.Check_System_ID = s.System_ID

where Week(c.Check_Date) = Week(Now())
and Year(c.Check_Date) = Year(Now())
```

*Returns the Following :*

```
Area_Name | Department_Name  |  System_ID   |  System_Name  |  Check_Date
Area 1      Department 1        1              System 1        2017-02-27
Area 1      Department 1        1              System 1        2017-02-27
Area 1      Department 1        2              System 2        2017-02-27
Area 1      Department 2        3              System 3        2017-02-27
```

What I'm trying to get to will group the areas, departments, systems etc. To show a count of how many *different* systems have been checked in the week.

*(I'm aware I haven't included any count or group-by in the query... I've left them out purposely to provide context. I have tried every possible way I can think but my knowledge is obviously lacking somewhere)*

**Desired Result**

```
Area_Name | Department_Name  |  Count_Checks
Area 1      Department 1        2
Area 1      Department 2        1
```

As you can see, the desired result has grouped the two `System 1` and treated them as 1 (as it's a single unique system), to show that over the last week, 2 different systems have been checked from department 1 and only 1 from department 2.

If anyone can shed some light... please do!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and aggregate using a combination of area/department as group:

```
SELECT a.Area_Name,
       d.Department_Name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.System_ID) AS Count_Checks
FROM departments d
LEFT JOIN areas a
    ON a.Area_ID = d.Department_Area
LEFT JOIN systems s
    ON s.System_Department = d.Department_ID
LEFT JOIN checks c
    ON c.Check_System_ID = s.System_ID  AND
       WEEK(c.Check_Date) = WEEK(NOW()) AND
       YEAR(c.Check_Date) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY a.Area_Name,
         d.Department_Name
```

One part of the query which might not be obvious is the code used to determine `Count_Checks`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT s.System_ID)
```

This will count, for each area/department group, the number of *distinct* system ID values.  In the case of Area 1/Department 1, this would yield a distinct system count of 2, while for Area 1/Department 2, this would give a count of just 1.

Comment: I think he wants `Area 1/Department 1 count=3`.

Comment: @SagarGangwal `to show that over the last week, 2 different systems have been checked from department 1 and only 1 from department 2`

Comment: Yes got it,as mention in desired output he wants `Area 1/Department 1 count=2`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Perfect answer, thanks a million. Managed to get close to this myself but fell short. The `Count(Distinct)` got me. Thanks again!

Comment: The condition in the WHERE clause should be moved to the last ON clause. Otherwise the LEFT JOIN will be converted to INNER JOIN as @Strawberry mentioned.